# How to display horizontal columns in oracle adf?

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I want to display horizontal columns instead of vertical. I am using oracle jdeveloper

Answer (score 0):

http://adfspecialists.blogspot.in/2013/02/using-afiterator-with-masterdetail.html   I got the answer,use this link it works properly.